# What programming language would be best to control an animation on a screen via sensor on Arduino? Java? C++?

Tags: java, c++, animation, arduino

I am working on a project where I want an image on a screen to be affected/modified in some way by sensor data coming from Arduino. (That is, maybe when the sensor gets the right reading the image becomes blurred and then unblurred when the sensor no longer has said values.)

I am using Arduino right now, the screen will most likely be my PC connection, so just my monitor for the time being.

What is the most suitable programming language for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either try [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) or the Arduino C language. It's mostly like [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) on some points, but you'll have to read the documentations first because they give a good hardware insight.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: the wikipedia page has led me to 'wiring' and 'frizting'. both designed along with processing specifically for artists. which is what i am. so thank you for pointing me in this direction. it saddens me to see a question such as this closed for not being "constructive" by people.

Comment: Well, they have a point according to their Q&A Format. I think there is another stackoverflow clone for such questions on the stack network (I am new at this too).